# How to show UIImage using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, uiimage, swiftui, swift5

I'm using a picker to grab an image from the phone gallery. It returns a UIImage which I want to show a thumbnail view of but I can't seem to convert it correctly?

truncated code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var image: UIImage? = nil
@State var thumbImage: Image? = nil
@State var showImagePicker: Bool = false
@State private var selectedImage = ""


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
         VStack {
                thumbImage = Image(UIImage: self.image)
                thumbImage!.resizable()
                    .frame(width: 299, height: 299)
                    .shadow(radius: 10)

                if (showImagePicker) {
                    OpenGallery(isShown: $showImagePicker, image: $image)
                }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Test")
    }
}
```

It just doesn't like the way I've used Image? navigationbartitle doesn't display either but not as big a problem for me atm.

Answer (score 2):

it would be nice if you would try out your "truncated" code first, because it was not compilable at all.

I had to change some things, but now it "runs" if you have the image in our Assets.

Here is my corrected code:

But I also have to say I am not sure what you exactly want to achieve....

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "80")
@State var thumbImage: Image? = nil
@State var showImagePicker: Bool = false
@State private var selectedImage = ""


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("aha")
                Image(uiImage: self.image!).resizable()
                    .frame(width: 299, height: 299)
                    .shadow(radius: 10)


            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Test")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look in the morning. All I am trying to do in the full project is to grab an image from the gallery (UIImage), show it on the screen (Image) and then try and pass into a ML model (UIImage)

Comment: Finally got around to trying this. I'm getting the following error, I'm assuming this is because I haven't picked an image yet?

    Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    
If I remove the forced unwrap, I am back at square one: Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'